# How can i add common interceptor class which will be called even before calling Rest Controller in the existing spring boot microservices project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I need to create a common interceptor class in the existing spring boot microservice project that will check & generate the tracing id or UUID (if one isn't present) which will propagate through out the execution path for tracing purpose. Now, how do i ensure that each service/api call will call this common interceptor class first & check the UUID then fwd the request to the controller so that tracing can be achieved. Also, where should i implement this. I mean, common interceptor should get called after the api gateway or where? i Please help me.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.